# Passing an HTML form and JS array to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have for example fields in my HTML form:

- GroupName = Group1
- GroupElements = 2
- Text1_1 = **empty**
- File1_1 = blah.jpg
- Text1_2 = Some text
- File1_2 = **empty**
- GroupName = Group2
- GroupElements = 1
- Text2_1 = **empty**
- File2_1 = blah2.jpg

User picks a group name, then decides of a number of elements, for each element he might choose to attach a file **OR** type in some text.

Later on I have a javascript array like this:

```
array[0][0] = GroupName; //Group1
array[0][1] = GroupElements; //2
array[0][2][0] = "#File1_1";
array[0][2][1] = "#Text1_2";

array[1][0] = GroupName; //Group2
array[1][1] = GroupElements; //1
array[1][2][0] = "#File2_1"; //this is an id of first chosen element (attached file **OR** text input)
```

At this point, I have yet no idea how to pass this data to .php file. I need to pass the whole array both with mixed-type elements (text or file)

Comment: Why don't you use JSON instead? Seems more natural to map the groups as objects inside JSON than as elements in an array

Comment: i think its better to use AJAX

Comment: Can you please post the names of these fields ?

Comment: Name of the fields are generated automatically, depending on the number of groups and number of elements in each group


The format is:

Text{group_id}_{element_id}
and
File{group_id}_{element_id}

If user takes 2 groups, with 2 elements in first group and 1 element in second group then the fields are

Text1_1, File1_1
Text1_2, File1_2

Text2_1, File2_1

Comment: can you please post some examples ? thanks 
I think there will be a way to recover your table directly from the $ _POST if the field names are properly indexed

exampel : 
Changing Text{group_id}_{element_id} to Text[group_id][element_id] then do a vardump of $_POST you will see 'Text' as an indexed array

Comment: If you have a JS object you can convert it to form data with jQuery's `$.param` and PHP will read this just fine. If you aren't using jQuery you can rip it out or find equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the way in which the fields are named: 
Here are some examples:

files fields are named differently to facilitate access to information about files posted

```html
<?php 
 if (!empty($_POST)) {
  echo "ALL POSTED DATA";
  var_dump($_POST);
  
  echo "POSTED TEXT";
  var_dump($_POST['Text']);
  
  echo "POSTED TEXT / Group 1";
  var_dump($_POST['Text']['g_1']);
 }
?>
<html>
<body>
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
  <div>
   <h4>Group 1 / Element 1</h4>
  <input type="text" name="Text[g_1][e_1][0]" value="aaaa" /> <!-- group 1 / element 1 / text 1 -->
  <input type="file" name="File[g_1_e_1_0]"  /> <!-- group 1 / element 1 / file 1 -->
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="Text[g_1][e_1][1]" value="bbbb" /> <!-- group 1 / element 1 / text 2 -->
  <input type="file" name="File[g_1_e_1_1]"  /> <!-- group 1 / element 1 / file 2 -->
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="Text[g_1][e_1][2]" value="cccc" /> <!-- group 1 / element 1 / text 3 -->
  <input type="file" name="File[g_1_e_1_2]"  /> <!-- group 1 / element 1 / file 3 -->
  </div>
  
  <div>
   <h4>Group 1 / Element 2 </h4>
   <input type="text" name="Text[g_1][e_2][0]" value="bbbb" /> <!-- group 1 / element 2 / text 1 -->
  <div>
  
  <div>
   <h4>Group 2 / Element 1 & 3</h4>
   <input type="text" name="Text[g_2][e_1][0]" value="aaaa" /> <!-- group 2 / element 1 / text 1 -->
   <input type="text" name="Text[g_2][e_3][0]" value="cccc" /> <!-- group 2 / element 3 / text 1 -->
  <div>
  <input type="submit" />
  
  
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are the results of test

```
ALL POSTED DATA
array
  'Text' => 
    array
      'g_1' => 
        array
          'e_1' => 
            array
              ...
          'e_2' => 
            array
              ...
      'g_2' => 
        array
          'e_1' => 
            array
              ...
          'e_3' => 
            array
              ...
POSTED TEXT
array
  'g_1' => 
    array
      'e_1' => 
        array
          0 => string 'aaaa' (length=4)
          1 => string 'bbbb' (length=4)
          2 => string 'cccc' (length=4)
      'e_2' => 
        array
          0 => string 'G1 E2' (length=5)
  'g_2' => 
    array
      'e_1' => 
        array
          0 => string 'G2' (length=2)
      'e_3' => 
        array
          0 => string 'cccc' (length=4)
POSTED TEXT / Group 1
array
  'e_1' => 
    array
      0 => string 'aaaa' (length=4)
      1 => string 'bbbb' (length=4)
      2 => string 'cccc' (length=4)
  'e_2' => 
    array
      0 => string 'G1 E2' (length=5)
```

```html
ALL POSTED FILES
array
  'File' => 
    array
      'name' => 
        array
          'g_1_e_1_0' => string 'log_10000715.txt' (length=16)
          'g_1_e_1_1' => string 'log_10001227.log' (length=16)
          'g_1_e_1_2' => string 'ts#2014-09.txt' (length=14)
      'type' => 
        array
          'g_1_e_1_0' => string 'text/plain' (length=10)
          'g_1_e_1_1' => string 'application/octet-stream' (length=24)
          'g_1_e_1_2' => string 'text/plain' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => 
        array
          'g_1_e_1_0' => string 'C:\servers\wamp\tmp\php6DCD.tmp' (length=31)
          'g_1_e_1_1' => string 'C:\servers\wamp\tmp\php6DDE.tmp' (length=31)
          'g_1_e_1_2' => string 'C:\servers\wamp\tmp\php6DDF.tmp' (length=31)
      'error' => 
        array
          'g_1_e_1_0' => int 0
          'g_1_e_1_1' => int 0
          'g_1_e_1_2' => int 0
      'size' => 
        array
          'g_1_e_1_0' => int 229920
          'g_1_e_1_1' => int 394400
          'g_1_e_1_2' => int 1068
```

Anas